# How to get a ManyToManyField object with user IDs in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a little built-in Chat with Django Channels and I created a Chat model where I can store the messages (it is like a CHAT ROOM with ID) and I want to get the single object by the 2 users ID.

I tried something like Chat.objects.filter(participiants__in=[ID1,ID2]) but it just returns every single chat they are in.

```py
def post(self,request):

        sender = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)

        message = request.data.get('message')
        post_id = request.data.get('post_id')
        recipient_id = request.data.get('recipient_id')

        chat_room = Chat.objects.filter(participiants__in=[sender, recipient_id])
```

```py
class Chat(models.Model):
    participiants = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name="chats")
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True, related_name="messages")

    def get_room_messages(self):
        messages = self.messages.order_by('-timestamp').all()
        return [[i.text,i.sender_id,i.link,i.post_id] for i in messages]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should then count the number of `participants` after filtering, and check if that is equal to `2`, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

chat_rooms = Chat.objects.filter(
    participiants__in=[sender, recipient_id]
).annotate(
    nparticipants=Count('participiants')
).filter(nparticipants=2)
```

If there is exactly one such `Chat` object, you can use `.get(..)` instead:

```
from django.db.models import Count

chat_rooms = Chat.objects.filter(
    participiants__in=[sender, recipient_id]
).annotate(
    nparticipants=Count('participiants')
).get(nparticipants=2)
```

Comment: It does not work, with filter it returns an empty array, with GET: "Chat matching query does not exist."

Comment: @mrkkrly: then there is, as the error says, no such `Chat` object, it is not said no such `Chat` object exists. I advise to inspect the database and see if there exists a `Chat` object with the two given participants.